# org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$NonZeroExitException: PhantomJS2 exited with code 2

Tags: scala.js

I am using scalatest as my testing framework, here is my test code :

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class SampleTest extends FunSuite{

   test("hello") {
     println(s"sdfsf")
   }
}
```

build.sbt settings

```
  val scalatestJS = libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %%% "scalatest" % Version.scalatest % Test

  val scalatestJSSettings = Seq(
    scalatestJS,
    scalaJSStage in Global := FastOptStage,
    //    scalaJSStage in Global := FullOptStage,
//    jsDependencies += RuntimeDOM,
//    jsDependencies += ProvidedJS / "test-bundle.js" % Test,
    jsEnv in Test := new PhantomJS2Env(scalaJSPhantomJSClassLoader.value, addArgs = Seq("--web-security=no"))
//        jsEnv in Test := new NodeJSEnv()
  )
```

Debug out :

```
[debug] Scala compilation took 0.961938628 s
[debug] Invalidating client/SampleTest.scala...
[debug] Invalidating (transitively) by inheritance from client/SampleTest.scala...
[debug] Initial set of included nodes: Set(client/SampleTest.scala)
[debug] Invalidated by transitive inheritance dependency: Set(client/SampleTest.scala)
[debug] The client/SampleTest.scala source file has the following implicit definitions changed:
[debug]         unconstrainedEquality, convertToEqualizer.
[debug] All member reference dependencies will be considered within this context.
[debug] New invalidations:
[debug]         Set()
[debug] Initial set of included nodes: Set()
[debug] Previously invalidated, but (transitively) depend on new invalidations:
[debug]         Set()
[debug] All newly invalidated sources after taking into account (previously) recompiled sources:Set()
[debug] Copy resource mappings: 
[debug]         
[info] Fast optimizing client/assets/client-test-fastopt.js
[debug] Linker: Compute reachability: 710892 us
[debug] Linker: Assemble LinkedClasses: 445560 us
[debug] Basic Linking: 1168893 us
[debug] Inc. optimizer: Batch mode: true
[debug] Inc. optimizer: Incremental part: 127681 us
[debug] Inc. optimizer: Optimizing 11793 methods.
[debug] Inc. optimizer: Optimizer part: 5987357 us
[debug] Inc. optimizer: 6140114 us
[debug] Refiner: Compute reachability: 243271 us
[debug] Refiner: Assemble LinkedClasses: 27389 us
[debug] Refiner: 272567 us
[debug] Emitter: Class tree cache stats: reused: 0 -- invalidated: 1375
[debug] Emitter: Method tree cache stats: resued: 0 -- invalidated: 6643
[debug] Emitter (write output): 1353125 us
[debug] Global IR cache stats: reused: 0 -- invalidated: 130 -- trees read: 1748
[debug] Loading JSEnv with linked file client/assets/client-test-fastopt.js
org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$NonZeroExitException: PhantomJS2 exited with code 2
        at org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$AbstractExtRunner.waitForVM(ExternalJSEnv.scala:107)
        at org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$ExtRunner.run(ExternalJSEnv.scala:156)
        at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.FrameworkDetector.detect(FrameworkDetector.scala:66)
        at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$60.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:737)
        at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$60.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:720)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (client/test:loadedTestFrameworks) org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$NonZeroExitException: PhantomJS2 exited with code 2
[error] Total time: 15 s, completed May 20, 2016 12:20:29 AM
```

Note : This is used to work fine but not anymore :s

**Edit :**

ScalaTest : 3.0.0-M15

ScalaJS : 0.6.9

Scala : 2.11.8

Phantom JS : 2.0.0

Comment: I suggest you mention the versions of PhantomJS, Scala.JS and ScalaTest you're using.

Comment: If this used to work but now doesn't, it's extremely likely to be an environmental change.  Did you update one of those components?  That would be a helpful lead for figuring out where the problem is...

Comment: the only thing i suspect is for server module(JVM only) i used scalatest with `%%%` but after that i fixed to `%%` , cleared .iv2 cache and  removed all target folders and did sbt clean but still no luck :s

Comment: I've had this stupid error a few times but can never remember how to fix it. To my astonishment once a machine reboot fixed it. I think another time it turned out to be an error in some of the ProvidedJS I was using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code i have a class which extends js class

```
@ScalaJSDefined
class MyLab(container : dom.Node) extends JSLab(container) {... }
```

even though i am not using this class in my tests,looks like source code generated for this line is some how looking for JSLab in global! which causes crash of phantomjs. Interestingly tests are executing fine on Rhino :s. anyhow i added JSLab as test dependency and error gone.

I don't know whom to blame here , whether its stupid developer(me) who went in different direction while solving problem or scala.js for not helpful in why phantomjs crashed :s

Comment: You can mostly blame Scala.js for not being helpful. You can also blame PhantomJS for making it hard for Scala.js to being helpful ...

Comment: hmm, btw same problem with scala-js-env-selenium(firefox/chrome) .